# How to avoid checking if a function exists before calling it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, destructuring

I need access to the formik props outside of the form.
While using refs, how can I avoid checking if a function exists before calling it?

```js
function BasicInfo({ event, initialValues, onSubmit }: Props) {
  const { coords } = useLocation();
  const { data: places, forward, getStaticMapUrl } = useMapbox();
  const { data: games, search, leanGame } = useGames();
  const throttle = useThrottle();

  const formRef = useRef<FormikProps<BasicInfoValues>>(null);
  const initValues: BasicInfoValues = initialValues || {
    title: '',
    game: { name: '' },
    address: '',
    starts_at: '',
    ends_at: '',
    coords: '',
  };

  const { setFieldValue, values, handleChange } = formRef.current || {};

  const handleEditLocationClick = function () {
    if (!setFieldValue) return;
    setFieldValue('address', '');
    setFieldValue('coords', '');
  };

  const renderLocation = function () {
    if (!values) return null;
    const { coords: coordinates, address } = values;
    if (coordinates && address) {
      const staticMapUrl = getStaticMapUrl({
        coords: JSON.parse(coordinates),
        width: 600,
        height: 165,
      });
      const { street, city } = parseAddress(address);
      return (
        <div className="basic-info__location">
          <div className="basic-info__location__image-container">
            <Image
              src={staticMapUrl}
              alt="static map"
              layout="fill"
              objectFit="fill"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="basic-info__location__address-container">
            <div className="basic-info__location__address-container__address">
              <span className="basic-info__location__street">{street}</span>
              <span className="basic-info__location__city">{city}</span>
            </div>
            <Button
              text="Edit location"
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              onClick={handleEditLocationClick}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AutoComplete<Feature>
          name="address"
          value={values.address}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (!handleChange) return;
            handleChange(e);
            throttle.wait(() => {
              if (!e.target.value) return;
              if (!coords) return;
              forward({
                coords,
                q: e.target.value,
              });
            }, 500);
          }}
          label="Venue location"
          placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
          items={places}
          Input={InputGroup}
          itemRenderer={(item) => <AddressItem placeName={item.place_name} />}
          onItemClick={(item) => {
            if (!setFieldValue) return;
            setFieldValue('address', item.place_name);
            setFieldValue('coords', JSON.stringify(item.center));
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={initValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} innerRef={formRef}>
      {({ values, handleChange, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form id="basic-info" className="basic-info">
          <FormSection
            title="Basic Info"
            description="Name your event and tell gamers what game will be played. Add
     details that highlight what makes it unique."
            icon="segment"
          >
            <InputGroup
              name="title"
              value={values.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Event title"
              placeholder="Be clear and descriptive"
            />
            <AutoComplete<Game>
              name="game.name"
              value={values.game.name}
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleChange(e);
                throttle.wait(() => {
                  if (!e.target.value) return;
                  search({ name: e.target.value, limit: 5 });
                }, 500);
              }}
              label="Featured game"
              placeholder="Search games"
              Input={InputGroup}
              items={games}
              itemRenderer={(item) => <GameItem game={item} />}
              onItemClick={(item) => {
                const game = leanGame(item);
                setFieldValue('game', game);
              }}
            />
            <span>
              Need game ideas?{' '}
              <Link href="/" passHref>
                <a className="link">Browse games by category</a>
              </Link>
            </span>
          </FormSection>
          <FormSection
            title="Location"
            description="Help gamers in the area discover your event and let attendees know where to show up."
            icon="map"
          >
            {renderLocation()}
          </FormSection>
          <FormSection
            title="Date and time"
            description="Tell gamers when your event starts and ends so they can make plans to attend."
            icon="date_range"
          >
            <InputGroup
              name="starts_at"
              value={values.starts_at}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Event starts"
              placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
              type="datetime-local"
              // icon="calendar_today"
            />
            <InputGroup
              name="ends_at"
              value={values.ends_at}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Event ends"
              placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
              type="datetime-local"
              // icon="calendar_today"
            />
          </FormSection>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Specifically this function where I check if `setFieldValue` exists:

```js
const handleEditLocationClick = function () {
    if (!setFieldValue) return;
    setFieldValue('address', '');
    setFieldValue('coords', '');
  };
```

There are other functions that also need formik props so I will have to do these checks. I guess I could pass in `setFieldValue` function as an argument to the `handleEditLocationClick` function, but that doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: Where is `handleEditLocationClick` used?

Comment: If it's called at points where `setFieldValue` is in scope, it sounds like you might be able to just define `handleEditLocationClick` in those children instead of in the parent here

Comment: @Bergi it's used within a helper render function outside of the form

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah, I would have to place the `renderLocation` function within the render prop as well. Just will look messy

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using ref at all here. Just pass the render prop parameter down to your helper functions:

```
function BasicInfo({ event, initialValues, onSubmit }: Props) {
  const { coords } = useLocation();
  const { data: places, forward, getStaticMapUrl } = useMapbox();
  const { data: games, search, leanGame } = useGames();
  const throttle = useThrottle();

  const initValues: BasicInfoValues = initialValues || {
    title: '',
    game: { name: '' },
    address: '',
    starts_at: '',
    ends_at: '',
    coords: '',
  };

  function renderLocation({ values, handleChange, setFieldValue }) {
    const handleEditLocationClick = function () {
      setFieldValue('address', '');
      setFieldValue('coords', '');
    };

    const { coords: coordinates, address } = values;
    if (coordinates && address) {
      const staticMapUrl = getStaticMapUrl({
        coords: JSON.parse(coordinates),
        width: 600,
        height: 165,
      });
      const { street, city } = parseAddress(address);
      return (
        <div className="basic-info__location">
          <div className="basic-info__location__image-container">
            <Image
              src={staticMapUrl}
              alt="static map"
              layout="fill"
              objectFit="fill"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="basic-info__location__address-container">
            <div className="basic-info__location__address-container__address">
              <span className="basic-info__location__street">{street}</span>
              <span className="basic-info__location__city">{city}</span>
            </div>
            <Button
              text="Edit location"
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              onClick={handleEditLocationClick}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AutoComplete<Feature>
          name="address"
          value={values.address}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleChange(e);
            throttle.wait(() => {
              if (!e.target.value) return;
              if (!coords) return;
              forward({
                coords,
                q: e.target.value,
              });
            }, 500);
          }}
          label="Venue location"
          placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
          items={places}
          Input={InputGroup}
          itemRenderer={(item) => <AddressItem placeName={item.place_name} />}
          onItemClick={(item) => {
            setFieldValue('address', item.place_name);
            setFieldValue('coords', JSON.stringify(item.center));
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={initValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} innerRef={formRef}>
      {({ values, handleChange, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form id="basic-info" className="basic-info">
          <FormSection
            title="Basic Info"
            description="Name your event and tell gamers what game will be played. Add
     details that highlight what makes it unique."
            icon="segment"
          >
            <InputGroup
              name="title"
              value={values.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Event title"
              placeholder="Be clear and descriptive"
            />
            <AutoComplete<Game>
              name="game.name"
              value={values.game.name}
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleChange(e);
                throttle.wait(() => {
                  if (!e.target.value) return;
                  search({ name: e.target.value, limit: 5 });
                }, 500);
              }}
              label="Featured game"
              placeholder="Search games"
              Input={InputGroup}
              items={games}
              itemRenderer={(item) => <GameItem game={item} />}
              onItemClick={(item) => {
                const game = leanGame(item);
                setFieldValue('game', game);
              }}
            />
            <span>
              Need game ideas?{' '}
              <Link href="/" passHref>
                <a className="link">Browse games by category</a>
              </Link>
            </span>
          </FormSection>
          <FormSection
            title="Location"
            description="Help gamers in the area discover your event and let attendees know where to show up."
            icon="map"
          >
            {renderLocation({ values, handleChange, setFieldValue })}
          </FormSection>
          <FormSection
            title="Date and time"
            description="Tell gamers when your event starts and ends so they can make plans to attend."
            icon="date_range"
          >
            <InputGroup
              name="starts_at"
              value={values.starts_at}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Event starts"
              placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
              type="datetime-local"
              // icon="calendar_today"
            />
            <InputGroup
              name="ends_at"
              value={values.ends_at}
              onChange={handleChange}
              label="Event ends"
              placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
              type="datetime-local"
              // icon="calendar_today"
            />
          </FormSection>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```